# Calculating XPath of XML file opened in Internet-Explorer-like browser

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xpath

Say, I have the following dummy XML file on my machine named Test.xml:

```
<bookstore>
<book>
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title> 
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author> 
    <year>2005</year> 
    <price>30.00</price> 
</book>
<book>
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title> 
    <author>J K. Rowling</author> 
    <year>2005</year> 
    <price>29.99</price> 
</book>
<book>
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title> 
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year> 
    <price>39.95</price> 
 </book>
 </bookstore>
```

When I open this XML file in Internet Explorer, the browser, on its own adds `<html>, <body>, <div> and <span>` tags to the XML file. 
I want to get XPath of`<year>`on highlighting that particular tag `(bookstore/book/year)`. Where do I start from?

Comment: IE doesn't "add" any of those things "to the XML file." It uses them when calculating an XML view, but they're not "in" the file, only in the rendered view. Where exactly are you trying to write your code?

Comment: You need to make sure that you are opening the file as XML, not as HTML. Then it won't be polluted with these HTML tags.

Comment: @EricLaw : The rendered view was what I was referring to. I am implementing my own browser based upon IE. So the code of trapping the xpath of the highlighted tag will be going in there.

Comment: The title of this post is "opened in Internet Explorer"-- do you then really mean "opened in a Web Browser Control"?

Comment: yes @EricLaw you could say that...

Comment: Good suggestion @MichaelKay. But how to make sure that the file is being opened as XML and not as HTML??

Comment: @Ashkay : IE makes this decision based on some complex combination of the media type in the HTTP header, the filename extension at the end of the URL, and configuration parameters. That's as much as I know. But the discussion above suggests we need to know far more about how you are opening the file before we can see what you are doing wrong.